# How do I write the click event for code below in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

how do I write the click event for code below?

[image]

```
    var prodName = ["Phlips camera","HP keyboard","iPad","iPhone","Dell Mouse","shirts","books","samsung mobiles","samsung TV",   "Phlips TV"," HP Mouse","iPad Charger","iPhone Charger","Dell Keyboard"," T shirts"," Ebooks"];

    var cartVal = [];

    //add to cart
    $('#addcart').live("click",function() 
    {   
        alert( prodName[id]+" Item Added");
        cartVal[item_count] = id;
        //alert("Item Count :::::" + item_count + " Selected Id::::  " + id);
        item_count++;
    }); 


    //create a list to display the selected product in the cart.

    for(var l=0 ;l< cartVal.length; l++)
    {
        //alert(" name  ::::"+ prodName[cartVal[l]]);
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.setAttribute('id','listitem_'+ l);
        listItem.setAttribute('data-icon','false');
        listItem.setAttribute('data-theme','c');

        listItem.innerHTML = "<a href='#' data-role='button' data-theme ='c' id='" + cartVal[l] + "' rel='external' data-inline='true' style='margin-left:1em;'> <font size='2'>"+ prodName[cartVal[l]] + "</font><span id='viewPage' class='ui-li-count'>View</span></a> <a href='#' id='delete' data-role='button' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='slideup'> Purchase album</a>";
            parent.appendChild(listItem);
    }
```

Here I want to write two click event for both anchor tag `<a>`.. if I click view or the product name, it display the details , then I click delete icon it deletes product the list..for e.g.: there is 5 items in the shopping list I want to delete two or three products?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Just do it..? (BTW it's spelt "Philips", and "anchor".)

Comment: I think no problem in philips. write click event for both anchor tag?

Comment: @Durai - Philips is spelled wrong it definitely needs an "i" after the "h". The "anchor" miss-spelling I fixed when tidying up the code.

Answer (score 1):

U can add the following function in onclick of the anchor tag for id delete

```
<a href='#' id='delete' **onclick=removeCurrentItem(event)** data-role='button' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='slideup'> Purchase album</a>

function removeCurrentItem(event){
var tar_ele;
if ($.browser.msie) {
// IE takes SRCELEMENT for event source.
// may the force shred IE.
tar_ele = $(e.srcElement);
} else {
tar_ele = $(e.target);
}
// remove the current Li tag
tar_ele.parent().find('li').remove();
}
```

similiarly for the View span u can have the following code

```
<a href='#' data-role='button' data-theme ='c' id='" + cartVal[l] + "' rel='external' data-inline='true' style='margin-left:1em;'> <font size='2'>"+ prodName[cartVal[l]] + "</font><span id='viewPage' class='ui-li-count' **onclick=showDetails(event)**>View</span></a>
```

where the showDetails function will show the details of the product.
for ex.

```
function showDetails (event){
    var tar_ele;
    if ($.browser.msie) {
    // IE takes SRCELEMENT for event source.
    // may the force shred IE.
    tar_ele = $(e.srcElement);
    } else {
    tar_ele = $(e.target);
    }
    // remove the current Li tag
    var id = tar_ele.parent('a').attr("id");
    // NOW do the requisiste display using the ID.
    }
```